# Is there any way to extract content of a pdf from bash?

Tags: bash

Is there any way to extract content of a pdf from bash? (I have a big folder of academic papers, which sadly have labels like "1010.3423.pdf". I'd like to write a bash script to name them more sensibly, which involves, say googling the first few lines.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to extract formatted text content from PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196621/how-to-extract-formatted-text-content-from-pdf)

Answer (score 4):

There is [pdftotext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext), which can help you get the title and authors from the pdf file. You can then use this to google, or generate a filename yourself.

Answer (score 4):

try pdftotext to extract the text? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext

Answer (score 2):

pdf2xml will get you more detailed information, I've been looking for such an utility last year, and among all, I think [pdf2xml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf2xml/?source=navbar) is the best.